# How to define and read yml value as Map<List<String>, List<String>> in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

I am trying to define and read yml value as `Map<List<String>, List<String>>`

Having below structure:

```
user.types:
   ['AB', 'BC', 'DD']: ['Admin', 'Test']
   ['RR', 'TT']: ['Admin']
   ['FF']: ['User']
```

I am not sure how to define this in yml. and trying to read with below class but not able to read it because of not well defined yml.

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class UserMapper {

    private Map<List<String>, List<String>> userMap;

    public Map<List<String>, List<String>> getUserMap() {
        return userMap;
    }

    @ConfigurationProperties("user.types")
    public void setUserMap(final Map<List<String>, List<String>> userMap) {
        this.userMap = userMap;
    }
}
```

How to define values in yml for this case and read it in spring boot?

Comment: Are you sure this is a valid yml?

Comment: Just added the format. I'm not sure how to define this in yml and read it.

Comment: I agree with @grekier. Looking at the official yaml documentation, it does not look like your user.types are valid yaml collections: https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#21-collections

Comment: I have added rough format and want to define in yml and read it as Map<List<String>,List<String>>. Defining in yml also added as a question